# Include old CSS file in webpack

Tags: css, webpack, css-modules, react-css-modules

I am migrating an old Angular app to React, so there is already the old build process with gulp that generates a CSS file. For React components I am using CSS modules, and Webpack is generating another CSS file. Finally using gulp I am concatenating the 2 css files.

The problem is that the styles that are generated by the Webpack (react-styles.css) appear also on the sourcemap of my old sass files (e.g.languages.sass) (although clicking on them the css correctly are not there)

[image]

Here is my webpack config for the react styles.

```
{
          test: /\.scss$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', combineLoaders([
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              query: {
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
              }
            }, {
              loader: 'sass-loader'
            }, {
              loader: 'autoprefixer-loader'
            }
          ]))
        }
```

**I think if I generate everything using Webpack will solve my issue. Is it a way to include my old sass files without converting them to css-module-generate class?**

Comment: Not entirely sure this will work, but try adding `devtool: 'source-map',` to your config.  I think you have some old map files hanging out that need to be overwritten.

Comment: @SandyGifford Unfortunately it didnt.